# Why did "find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm * " delete all files?

Tags: find

The expected behaviour was to delete all .jpgs, but it deleted all files in the directory.

How can the command be changed to find and delete all xyz files?

Comment: Remember that special symbols are processed by shell, not programs. * is replaced with file names *before* `find` or `rm` gets started.

Comment: Within find, the character that means "the name of the file just found" is {}. So if you want to delete all jpg files, you could say: find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec rm {} \;  This deletes all files one by one, as soon as they are found. This is a waste (better do them all in one go), but illustrates that there a symbol which substitutes for the name of the file just found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You executed `rm * result1.jpg result2.jpg result3.jpg ...`, *not* `rm result1.jpg result2.jpg result3.jpg ...`, thereby deleting everything matching `*` through shell expansion.

But you don't even need `xargs` for this simple task.

---

Run `find ... -type f -print` first, in case you're not confident about your expression. Make sure you like the results.

Then, run `find ... -type f -delete`.